# Insert empty data not null

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using a SQLLite Database and I want to copy values from one table to another. So I found this:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`row_id`, `daystamp`, `column1`, `column2`) SELECT `position`, 2015813, `column1`, `column2` FROM `table2`
```

The problem is that the "table1" has more columns than the four.
As result the other columns are null, but I didn't want them to be null.
So I add to every column "NOT NULL" and I get the error after exeucting the SQLQuery above:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: table1.colum3: INSERT INTO `table1` (`row_id`, `daystamp`, `column1`, `column2`) SELECT `position`, 2015813, `column1`, `column2` FROM `table2`
```

I want that the cells are empty. How should I do this, without put every column in the query?

Comment: `NOT NULL` constraint is to prevent null values in table. If you want to fill the table with blanks, you have to add those columns to the SQL by ommiting nulls with NVL function, see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `Default value` for those columns while creating your table (or) perform a `ALTER` and provide a default value like

```
colum3 varchar(10) default ''
```

You can as well change your `INSERT` statement to insert some default values for those columns like

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`row_id`, `daystamp`, `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`, `column5`) 
SELECT `position`, 2015813, `column1`, `column2`,
DEFAULT(), DEFAULT(), DEFAULT() 
FROM `table2`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the columns and the values in the `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`row_id`, `daystamp`, `column1`, `column2`, column3, column4)
    SELECT `position`, 2015813, `column1`, `column2`, <some value>, <some value>
    FROM `table2`;
```

Alternatively, when you define the table, you need to specify a `DEFAULT` value along with `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`row_id`, `daystamp`, `column1`, `column2`) SELECT `position`, 2015813, NVL(`column1`, ''), NVL(`column2`, '') FROM `table2`
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in You Old Table Data And column Has Not A null Row That Create Problem To Copy To One Table To other Table .....

Beacuse You Set All column Not Null But In old Table You Not Set The Not NUll So i think Problem In your Old Table Row